# Having trouble selecting all input element text on mouse click in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, onfocus

I've had great success with the following in the latest IE/Chrome:

```
<input value="Test"/>
<script>
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/query", "dojo/domReady!"], function(on, query){
    var blah = query("input")[0];
    on(blah, "focus", function(e){
   this.setSelectionRange(0,9999);
});
});
</script>
```

The purpose is to select all the text in an input element when they click it (just like how it selects all text when tabbing in by default), so when they start typing it erases what was in there and starts afresh.

However, in Firefox (SeaMonkey too) even with the above code something SOMETIMES unselects the text on mouseup and reverts to the default case of putting the caret where the user clicks and selecting nothing. You will always see that the text is all selected at least for a split second.

What can I do? Any suggestions?

See fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/avxra2q2/11/

Comment: Who voted that this question is not about programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really can't figure out why this is happening in firefox and I also tested what are you doing in jquery and also the recommended way by MDN(Mozilla Developer network), and because of that I am going to assume it is a bug.

but I got you a temp solution that will work, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/avxra2q2/17/) in JSfiddle I got to this answer because my experience with browsers especially when you are playing with focus and cursors things doesn't go your way so the browser need some time.

you can also look at the code below

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/query","dojo/has", "dojo/sniff", "dojo/domReady!"], function(on, query,has,sniff){
    var blah = query("input")[0];
    on(blah, "focus", function(e){

        if(has("ff")){ // only firefox 
       var myVar = setTimeout(function(){
                      clearTimeout(myVar);
                     blah.focus();
                blah.setSelectionRange(0,9999);      
                   },150);
        }else{
              this.setSelectionRange(0,9999);
        }

});
});
```